# Sending an Email alert using Visual Flows?

Tags: customer-community, email-alert, visual-flows

I am very new to the Flows. Already I came across this link: **[Visual Flow Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_action_email_flow.htm)**  which just gave some definitions for the fields but not the execution.

I've already configured a Process flow that creates a Child record immediately after a Parent record created(lookup). Now I wanted to send out an email to all the Customer Community users with child record's information whenever a parent record gets created. But I am not sure how to implement this complete process - Creating a Parent record/Send email out using a Visual flow.

Also is it possible to have a Multi-select picklist to display of all the Customer Community users for selecting to send out the email?

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly do not want to use a multi-select picklist for your Customer Community unless it is extremely small, say <50 users. Even at 50 users there are much more efficient ways to selecting recipients. Why are you specifically asking about that option? What problem are you trying to solve with the second part of your question?

Comment: Our users want to have a flexibility to select/deselect/select all/clear all recipients before sending out the email. Because, the email would only make sense to a specific community user(s) who will need to respond back.